# How do I get yes to not run if a yes/no question isn't asked?

Tags: bash, macos

The yes command seems to run in a loop when a yes/no question is never asked. I thought it shouldn't do that if piped with another command.

I have a bash script I am using on OS X Mojave that binds a computer to Active Directory. All of these computers already have computer records in AD but higher ups decided they wanted a new computer naming scheme and the only way we can get the Macs to update their names is to unbind from AD then rebind. Some of the computers were not unbinding cleanly (removing the computer record from the AD) and in that case I did a force unbind, which leaves the computer record. The problem is when binding them again. Sometimes the system sees that the computer record already exists and asks if I want to use the existing record, which I do because it will change the computer record name in AD. But sometimes, when the computer unbind cleanly, it never asks that question. I have piped the yes command right before the dsconfigad command and when it asks if I want to use the existing record it works fine. But, when it doesn't ask it gets stuck in a loop running yes.

```
yes | dsconfigad -a $currentName -u $aduname -p $adpass -ou "OU=Macs,DC=domain,DC=com" -domain $domain -mobile enable -mobileconfirm disable -localhome enable -useuncpath enable -groups "Domain Admins" -alldomains enable
```

I was hoping that if the yes/no question wasn't asked it would just move on.

Comment: `yes` *always*, unconditionally, just keeps writing `yes` (by default) or another string (if given) to its stdout, until the program that stdout is written to exits. That's its intended, designed behavior; the reason that behavior is often correct is that if the receiving program doesn't *read* input at all, then the sending program (`yes`) will just get an EOF and exit when the receiving program closes its stdin on finish.

Comment: If you have a program that reads its stdin indefinitely, that program should not be used with `yes`. Look into how to avoid the prompt altogether (well-written UNIX tools don't unconditionally prompt! -- they'll either have a command-line flag or an environment variable that avoids it, or fallback behavior when stdin is a non-TTY handle), or use a tool like `pexpect`/`expect`/`empty`/etc.

Comment: Note also that a pipe is *one-way*. When you pipe `foo | bar`, the output of `foo` is connected to the input of `bar`, but that's the *only* direction the connection goes in; `foo` has no way of knowing what `bar` prompted for.

Comment: These were all great answers, I am still learning how certain commands work. Thank you. It seems I will have to go about this a different way.